# How to center this image inside a container?

Tags: html, css

I've tried quite a few answers, but none give the expected result which is the image centered horizontally.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="text" class="text" >
    <label for="client">Client:</label>
    <input list="client" class="form-control" id="client" name="client" disabled="">
    <label for="style">Style:</label>
    <input list="style" class="form-control" id="style" name="style" disabled="">
    <input type="hidden" list="itemId" class="form-control" id="itemId" name="itemId" disabled="" value="BOA-230109-A">
  </div>
  <div id="imageDiv" class="image">
    <img id="image" alt="Item image" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1832ZxN4bbNhNVlHV1hZUVjTjcR8dm" height="120" width="160">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just style the **imageDiv** with `text-align: center;`

```css
#imageDiv {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="text" class="text" >
    <label for="client">Client:</label>
    <input list="client" class="form-control" id="client" name="client" disabled="">
    <label for="style">Style:</label>
    <input list="style" class="form-control" id="style" name="style" disabled="">
    <input type="hidden" list="itemId" class="form-control" id="itemId" name="itemId" disabled="" value="BOA-230109-A">
  </div>
  <div id="imageDiv" class="image">
    <img id="image" alt="Item image" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1832ZxN4bbNhNVlHV1hZGUuUVjTjcR8dm" height="120" width="160">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seeing ```text-align``` I wouldn't think it'd do images. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By default, images display **inline**, which means they are rendered as part of the surrounding text. In your case, **imageDiv** doesn't contain any text, either before or after the image, but if it did, you'd see what I mean.